# Actionscript 3 gotoAndStop in a branching storyline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web-applications

I have created a simple gotoAndStop storybook in Flash but it's following branching storyline. The knight entered a castle and there is one gate. Upon entering the gate, he faced 3 more doors and each door, leads to another series of rooms.

However, the end will be the same. It appears to be a simple "gotoAndStop" codes but at the end of the of the story, the knight will earn some sort of price (represented by a frame) depending on which doors he entered. My question is, how will I know which buttons the user clicked so that i can "gotoAndStop" him to a certain frame? The final destination or award frame of user depends on which buttons he clicked.

This is my sample gotoAndStop code that I used in the storybook(similar code I used in all frames, just changing the button instance names, function names and frame labels):

```
nextbutton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, proceedDoor1);
function proceedDoor1 (e:Event){
    gotoAndStop("door1")
}
```

I am complete novice so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: Store the metadata in some object declared as `public var` so it'll be persistent across frames, then once it'll be time to show the reward you query what you've stored, and select which frame should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little mockup I made (Apologies if it's a bit messy).  It requires 5 empty frames on the timeline starting from 1.

Each door will have a `MouseEvent.CLICK` event listener that will take you to the desired frame.  In this case, I made each door lead directly to the prize frame.  But you could always make each door lead to another set of doors and then have those doors lead to the prize etc. etc.

Note that the variables are just for creating the buttons, and are not needed.  You can place the click event listener on your own movieclips and achieve the same results. (You'd just need to adjust instance names in the code)

Hope this helps!

Frame1 code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var rec:Sprite = new Sprite();
rec.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
rec.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
addChild(rec);
rec.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
rec.y=stage.stageHeight/2;

var text1:TextField=new TextField();
text1.wordWrap=true;
text1.text="ENTER THE CASTLE";
addChild(text1);
text1.x=rec.x;
text1.y=rec.y;

rec.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,recC);

function recC (e:Event):void{
    //Remove Child not needed if you symbols are placed manually on stage
    removeChild(rec);
    removeChild(text1);
    rec.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,recC)
    nextFrame();
}
```

Frame2 code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();


var rec2: Sprite = new Sprite();
rec2.graphics.beginFill(0x0066CC, 1);
rec2.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
addChild(rec2);
rec2.x = stage.stageWidth / 5;
rec2.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

var rec3: Sprite = new Sprite();
rec3.graphics.beginFill(0x66FF99, 1);
rec3.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
addChild(rec3);
rec3.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
rec3.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;


var rec4: Sprite = new Sprite();
rec4.graphics.beginFill(0xFF3333, 1);
rec4.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
addChild(rec4);
rec4.x = stage.stageWidth / 1.2;
rec4.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

var text2: TextField = new TextField();
addChild(text2);
text2.text = "Pick a Door Knight!";
text2.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
text2.y = stage.stageHeight / 4;


//Each door has an event listener for a click
//Once clicked, the door will take you to the appropriate ending

rec2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec2C);

function rec2C(e: Event): void {
    removeChild(rec2);
    removeChild(rec3);
    removeChild(rec4);
    removeChild(text2);
    rec2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec2C)
    rec3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec3C)
    rec4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec4C)
    gotoAndStop(3)//This is the frame for Blue
}

rec3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec3C);

function rec3C(e: Event): void {
    removeChild(rec2);
    removeChild(rec3);
    removeChild(rec4);
    removeChild(text2);
    rec2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec2C)
    rec3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec3C)
    rec4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec4C)
    gotoAndStop(4)//This is the frame for Green
}

rec4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec4C);

 function rec4C(e: Event): void {
    removeChild(rec2);
    removeChild(rec3);
    removeChild(rec4);
    removeChild(text2);
    rec2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec2C)
    rec3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec3C)
    rec4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rec4C)
    gotoAndStop(5)//This is the frame for Red
}
```

Frame 3 code:

```
var text3: TextField = new TextField();
addChild(text3);
text3.wordWrap=true;
text3.text = "You won the blue prize!";
text3.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
text3.y = stage.stageHeight / 2.7;

addChild(rec2);
rec2.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
rec2.y=stage.stageWidth/2;
```

Frame 4 code:

```
var text4: TextField = new TextField();
addChild(text4);
text4.wordWrap=true;
text4.text = "You won the green prize!";
text4.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
text4.y = stage.stageHeight / 2.7;

addChild(rec3);
rec3.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
rec3.y=stage.stageWidth/2;
```

Frame 5 code:

```
var text5: TextField = new TextField();
addChild(text5);
text5.wordWrap=true;
text5.text = "You won the red prize!";
text5.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
text5.y = stage.stageHeight / 2.7;

addChild(rec4);
rec4.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
rec4.y=stage.stageWidth/2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use multiple frames this is probably not the best way.
You can use one frame only, add and remove items when the user click on a Button...

If you use multiple frames, you may just use one single click handler and do what you want by checking which Button is clicked in the handler.

If you want to use multiple frames :

On your first frame, you have one button named door_1 (which is an instance of DoorButton)
Let's imagine you have a DoorButton class that extends SimpleButton.
in the DoorButton class you may just add methods to declare "id" and a "targetFrame" properties...

DoorButton class:

```
package {

import flash.display.SimpleButton;

    public class DoorButton extends SimpleButton {

        private var _id;
        private var _targetFrame;
        public static const FRAME1:String = "frame1";
        public static const FRAME2:String = "frame2";
        public static const FRAME3:String = "frame3";
        public static const FRAME4:String = "frame4";
        public static const FRAME5:String = "frame5";
        // ...      
        public function DoorButton(){
            super();
        }
        public function set id(id:uint):void {
            _id = id;
        }
        public function get id():uint {
            return _id;
        }
        public function set targetFrame(target:String):void {
            _targetFrame = target;
        }
        public function get targetFrame():String {
            return _targetFrame;
        }

    }
}
```

code on frame 1:

```
import DoorButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var door1:DoorButton = door_1;
door1.id = 1;
door1.targetFrame = DoorButton.FRAME2;
door1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,proceed);

function proceed(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var b:DoorButton = e.target as DoorButton;
    switch (b.id){
        case 1 :
            trace("should go in : " + b.targetFrame);
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            // call some function here
            break;
        case 2 :
            trace("should go in : " + b.targetFrame);
            // call some function here
            break;
        case 3 :
            trace("should go in : " + b.targetFrame);
            // call some function here
            break;
        case 4 :
            trace("should go in : " + b.targetFrame);
            // call some function here
            break;
    }
}
stop()
```

On your second frame, you have tree instances of DoorButton named:
door_2, door_3, door_4

code on frame 2 :

```
var door2:DoorButton = door_2;
var door3:DoorButton = door_3;
var door4:DoorButton = door_4;

door2.id = 2;
door2.targetFrame = DoorButton.FRAME3;
door2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,proceed);

door3.id = 3;
door3.targetFrame = DoorButton.FRAME4;
door3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,proceed);

door4.id = 4;
door4.targetFrame = DoorButton.FRAME5;
door4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,proceed);
```

Then, you may do this for each frame and just call the "proceed" method to do want you want.
But I suggest you to avoid multiple frames anyway..

This is real basic, and you will may add some statements to avoid to reinitialize the Buttons if you plan to come back on the timeline and replay or let the user to change his mind and come back to open another door...
I just hope that may help you.

Try it, then, feel free to ask.

Best regards.

Comment: Coding on multiple frames is extremely hard to handle in pure AS3 and OOP coding!...
I just try this code, but if you want to change something, you have to hide / show the buttons, you will get a lot of job!
All the instances have to be present on the Timeline or you have to rewrite the code each time you want to replay the App...

Consider to keep each instances on the first frame, and definitelly forget about a timeline based App!
This was interesting to me because I never use multiples Key-frames.
Thank you for your question so ;)

Comment: yes! thank you for the insights! Indeed, it's hard to code in multiple frames but it worked for me (though it is not best way). I have tried coding all in just first frame but errors keep popping out. So timeline based coding worked for me :D

Comment: For sure, but You should avoid it ;)